# Should I use orbited or gevent for integrating comet functionality into a django app

Tags: python, django, postgresql, comet, gevent

I have been working with Django for some time now and have written several apps on a setup that uses Apache 2 mod_wsgi and a PostgreSQL database on ubuntu.

I have aa app that uses xsendfile to serve files from Apache via a Django view, and also allow users to upload files via a form as well.  All this working great, but I now want to ramp up the features (and the complexity I am sure) by allowing users to chat and to see when new files have been uploaded without refreshing their browser.

As I want this to be scale-able, I don't want to poll continually with AJAX as this is going to get very heavy with large numbers of users.

I have read more posts, sites and blogs then I can count on integrating comet functionality into a Django app but there are so many different opinions out there on how to do this that I am now completely confused.

Should I be using orbited, gevent, iosocket?
Where does Tornado fit into this debate?

I want the messages also be stored on the database, so do I need any special configuration 
to prevent my application blocking when writing to the database?
Will running a chat server with Django have any impact on my ability to serve files from Apache?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend using WebSockets for bidirectional realtime communication. Keep running Django as is and run a WebSocket server on another port. As far as your database blocking, yes, you'll need to keep that in mind as you write your WebSocket server and either use a non-blocking database driver, or address that in some way.

Client-side you'll want to use [Socket.IO](http://socket.io) or [web-socket-js](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js) to support flash fallback for older browsers which don't support flash.

For the server, I would lean towards gevent or tornado, personally. For gevent there is [gevent-websocket](http://www.gelens.org/code/gevent-websocket/) and [gevent-socketio](https://bitbucket.org/Jeffrey/gevent-socketio), for tornado you get built-in WebSocket support and can use [tornadio](https://github.com/MrJoes/tornadio) if you want to use Socket.IO. [Eventlet](http://eventlet.net/doc/modules/websocket.html) and [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/export/29073/branches/websocket-4173-2/doc/web/howto/websocket.xhtml) both support WebSockets as well. There is also a pretty cool new project called [autobahn](http://www.tavendo.de/autobahn) which is built on twisted, and [meinheld](https://github.com/mopemope/meinheld) has WebSocket middleware you can use.

WebSockets are pretty exciting, and as such there are tons of great posts out there on the subject. I found these posts useful:

- http://gehrcke.de/2011/06/the-best-and-simplest-tools-to-create-a-basic-websocket-application-with-flash-fallback-and-python-on-the-server-side/
- http://codysoyland.com/2011/feb/6/evented-django-part-one-socketio-and-gevent/
- http://toastdriven.com/blog/2011/jul/31/gevent-long-polling-you/
- http://blog.jupo.org/post/8858247674/real-time-web-apps-with-django-and-websockets/

Comment: Thanks, now that I have a direction I can see things a lot more clearly. django-socketio, from the last link looks particularly interesting as the article has good detail on djano integration and a chat sample app!

Comment: Just a note, psycopg2 has supported greening for some time, see the psycogreen project on bitbucket (by the psycopg2 author) for how you would green postgres in a gevent environment. https://bitbucket.org/dvarrazzo/psycogreen/src/77a9c05f5229/gevent/psyco_gevent.py

Comment: psycopg2 was a good tip.  I have been trying out socketio but I still can't figure out how I can use this while keeping my app in apache (which I need to keep using xsendfile)

Comment: You need to run the websocket server on a separate port, using a standalone process. If you need more than one process to handle a huge amount of websocket connections you can use haproxy or the nginx_tcp_proxy_module (with nginx) to load balance between them.

Comment: If you want to stick nginx in front of your websocket server you'll want to use https://github.com/yaoweibin/nginx_tcp_proxy_module as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Apache + X-Sendfile you could use Nginx + X-Accel-Redirect. That way you can run a gevent/wsgi/django server behind Nginx with views that provide long-polling. No need for a separate websockets server.

I've used both Apache + X-Sendfile and Nginx + X-Accel-Redirect to serve (access-protected) content on Webfaction without any problems.